# AWS Rekognition returns InvalidS3ObjectException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

I've been trying to figure-out what seems wrong with my program.

I followed the documentation for aws rekognition->compareFaces().
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/APIReference/API_CompareFaces.html

the S3->getObject() is working fine, I get the image. But when I used the same variables for compareFaces() S3Object, I got this error:

```
InvalidS3ObjectException (client): Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions.
```

I already checked my key/region/access permissions. all is correct but it still now working.
Here's my code:

```
    $bucket = 'bucket';
    $region = 'region';
    $timeIn = 'path/to/folder/name1.jpg';
    $timeOut = 'path/to/folder/name2.jpg';

    $s3 = new S3Client([
        'version' => 'latest', 
        'region' => $region,
    ]);

    $sourceImage = $s3->getObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key' => $timeIn,
    ])['Body'];
    
    $rekognition = new RekognitionClient([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region' => $region
    ]);
    
    $result = $rekognition->compareFaces([
        'SimilarityThreshold' => 80,
        'SourceImage' => [
            'S3Object' => [
                'Bucket' => $bucket,
                'Name' => $timeIn,
                'Version' => 'latest',
            ],
        ],
        'TargetImage' => [
            'S3Object' => [
                'Bucket' => $bucket,
                'Name' => $timeOut,
                'Version' => 'latest',
            ],
        ],
    ]);
```

Comment: The error messages suggests that it is trying to call `GetObjectMetadata()`. What permissions have been assigned to the IAM User / IAM Role that is running this code?

Comment: I think I found the problem, it seems that it has error reading the image? the first images im comparing has no face/person. just room background. 

then i tried, changing the images with face/person. and its now working.

it just weird. maybe the library shoud return 0% or no face detected error?